# Choosing a Null if null else Maximum : oracle SQL

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a requirement to choose only one value : null if a column is null else maximum of value in a column. Can someone help ?

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to edit your question to provide more information so that we actually stand a chance of being able to help you? Sample data along with the expected output would be a big help.

Comment: `select max(mycolumn) from mytable` ?  That returns null if there are no values in the column, else the maximum.

Comment: For example: consider this query:select * from customer where customerID is null or (select max(customerID) from customer )......... This results 2 rows..but I want only one row...I know that's wrong query..but i gave it just for your understanding

Comment: What the query should give if for example 2 record contain NULL in this column, and other records contains some values ? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete, i'm writing the answer based on the assumptions

```
with subq as (select max(column) m from table)
select case m is null then null else m end val from subq;
```